# Comparing varying datetime formats to a standard datetime in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've got this program which takes in `n` amount of csv files and sanitizes the data within each file before sending the files on their way into the database. When each file comes in from the field they most of the time have the datetime format of `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S`. But sometimes we have the need to log data at highspeed and we'll see files come back with this format, `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f`.

I have a function, `ParseTime()`, which crashes with a `ValueError` and I'm having a hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong. My goal is to decide if `line` is in seconds or milliseconds format, and then have the `ParseTime()` function return the appropriate string. But the program crashes every time.

**Here's the traceback:**

```
C:\Users\klucas\PycharmProjects\DataCleanupScript\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\klucas\PycharmProjects\DataCleanupScript\main.py 
Hello klucas please wait while the script cleans the data. This may take a few moments depending on network speed and the amount of files.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\klucas\PycharmProjects\DataCleanupScript\main.py", line 38, in <module>
    DataCleanupScript.DoWork(TD_files, source, destination)  # clean the data
  File "C:\Users\klucas\PycharmProjects\DataCleanupScript\DataCleanupScript.py", line 11, in DoWork
    CleanUpData(f)  # clean up the data
  File "C:\Users\klucas\PycharmProjects\DataCleanupScript\DataCleanupScript.py", line 24, in CleanUpData
    IsDataValid(f, r1, data, trend_header_tuple, machine_header_tuple)  # check to see if the data is valid
  File "C:\Users\klucas\PycharmProjects\DataCleanupScript\DataCleanupScript.py", line 56, in IsDataValid
    valid = valid and CheckDates(f, line, trend_header_tuple)  # Check the dates next
  File "C:\Users\klucas\PycharmProjects\DataCleanupScript\DataCleanupScript.py", line 65, in CheckDates
    ParseTime(line)  # check the time format for each row
  File "C:\Users\klucas\PycharmProjects\DataCleanupScript\DataCleanupScript.py", line 89, in ParseTime
    raise ValueError('no valid date format found.')
ValueError: no valid date format found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**And here is the meat & potatoes of my program:**

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os
import stat
import shutil


# A function which cleans the data.
def CleanUpData(f):
    IsTrendFile(f)  # check to see if file is a trend file
    IsFileReadOnly(f)  # check to see if file is read only
    with open(f, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as g:  # open file as read
        r1 = csv.reader((line.replace('\0', '') for line in g))  # declare read variable while stripping nulls
        trend_header_tuple = next(r1)  # get trend header
        machine_header_tuple = next(r1)  # get machine header
        data = []  # initialize data list
        IsDataValid(f, r1, data, trend_header_tuple, machine_header_tuple)  # check to see if the data is valid
    WriteData(f, data, trend_header_tuple, machine_header_tuple)  # write the data to the file


def IsDataValid(f, r1, data, trend_header_tuple, machine_header_tuple):
    for line in r1:  # for each line in the trend file
        if line:  # if it is a line
            valid = False  # initialize the variable to False

            if len(line) == len(trend_header_tuple):  # if the length of the line = length of the trend_header_tuple
                valid = True  # the data is valid
            elif len(line) == len(machine_header_tuple):  # elseif the length of the line = length of the machine_header_tuple
                valid = True  # the data is valid

            valid = valid and CheckDates(f, line, trend_header_tuple)  # Check the dates next

            if valid:  # if everything checks out as valid...
                data.append(line)  # append the current line to the data variable


# A function which compares the dates of each index of a csv to the date in the trend_header_tuple. If the row_time comes
# before base_time, the check fails.
def CheckDates(f, line: str, trend_header_tuple):
    ParseTime(line)  # check the time format for each row
    row_time = datetime.strptime(line[0], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')  # strip the time from each row to get a time object
    orig_time = trend_header_tuple[1] + ' ' + trend_header_tuple[2]  # concatenate the trend_header_tuple into a string
    base_time = datetime.strptime(orig_time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')  # get a time object from the trend_header_tuple

    td = row_time - base_time  # calculate the time difference (a negative number indicates a time before base_time)

    line = line[0].strip()  # strip the time

    if td < timedelta(0):  # if td is negative
        print(f'    This line is before the base time and has been stripped:')  # print some stuff to the user:
        print(f'    {line}')  # which line was stripped
        print(f'    {f}')  # which file it was in
        return False  # the check fails
    return True  # the check passes


# A function to decide if the row_time is in %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S or %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f datetime format.
def ParseTime(line: str):
    for fmt in ('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'):  # for each format
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(str(line), fmt)  # strip the line
        except ValueError:
            pass
        raise ValueError('no valid date format found.')
```

**So my question is this**: Each row's `row_time` is compared to a standard datetime which is in the `trend_header_tuple`. I want to look at each row of a csv file and decide if the `row_time` in that row is in one of these two formats: `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S`, `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f`. If a file can be in either of the two datetime formats, what is the best way to achieve this? Do I need to move the `row-time`, `orig-time`, and `base_time` calculations into the `ParseTime()` function? Is there an easier way I'm just not aware of?

**Sample Input 1:**

```
TD,08/24/2021,14:14:08,21012,223,0,1098,0,031,810,12,01,092,048,0008,02
Date/Time,G120010,M129000,G110100,M119030,G112070,G112080,G111030,G127020,G127030,G120020,G120030,G121020,G111040,G112010,P102000,G112020,G112040,G112090,G110050,G110060,G110070,T111100
06/27/2022 00:00:01,40,133.2,0,0,7.284853,0,0.6030464,0,0,1,0,5,11,5,0,0,414,344,0,154,0,5
06/27/2022 00:00:03,40,133.2,0,0,7.284853,0,0.5898247,0,0,1,0,5,11,5,0,0,414,344,0,154,0,5
06/27/2022 00:00:05,40,133.2,0,0,7.284853,0,0.6135368,0,0,1,0,5,11,5,0,0,414,344,0,154,0,5
06/27/2022 00:00:07,40,133.2,0,0,7.284853,0,0.6087456,0,0,1,0,5,11,5,0,0,414,344,0,154,0,5
06/27/2022 00:00:09,40,133.2,0,0,7.284853,0,0.5903625,0,0,1,0,5,11,5,0,0,414,344,0,154,0,5
06/27/2022 00:00:11,40,133.2,0,0,7.284853,0,0.5799789,0,0,1,0,5,11,5,0,0,414,344,0,154,0,5
06/27/2022 00:00:13,40,133.2,0,0,7.284853,0,0.5821953,0,0,1,0,5,11,5,0,0,414,344,0,154,0,5
06/27/2022 00:00:15,40,133.2,0,0,7.284853,0,0.6024017,0,0,1,0,5,11,5,0,0,414,344,0,154,0,5
06/27/2022 00:00:17,40,133.2,0,0,7.284853,0,0.5984001,0,0,1,0,5,11,5,0,0,414,344,0,154,0,5
06/27/2022 00:00:19,40,133.2,0,0,7.284853,0,0.5815544,0,0,1,0,5,11,5,0,0,414,344,0,154,0,5
```

**Sample Input 2:**

```
TD,1/4/2022,13:46:23,20046,004,2,2010,0,12,20,12,1,140,184,5,3
Date/Time,G118030,G118040,G118050,G118110,G118120,G118130,G118140,G118020,G118150,G118160,G118170,G118190
08/03/2022 23:59:58.301,0,0,0,1679.126,2123.999,1076.921,6371.996,2165.787,-344.5032,46.11444,523.5406,611.683
08/03/2022 23:59:58.426,0,0,0,1668.278,2102.297,1087.772,6393.695,2149.005,-344.5032,46.11444,523.5406,611.683
08/03/2022 23:59:58.551,0,0,0,1657.427,2113.148,1087.772,6393.695,2151.773,-333.6521,46.11444,523.5406,606.7005
08/03/2022 23:59:58.677,0,0,0,1646.576,2113.148,1076.921,6393.695,2146.284,-333.6521,46.11444,523.5406,606.7005
08/03/2022 23:59:58.801,0,0,0,1646.576,2113.148,1087.772,6393.695,2147.658,-344.5032,46.11444,523.5406,611.683
08/03/2022 23:59:58.926,0,0,0,1668.278,2113.148,1087.772,6415.397,2155.956,-344.5032,46.11444,523.5406,611.683
08/03/2022 23:59:59.052,0,0,0,1657.427,2113.148,1087.772,6382.844,2151.773,-333.6521,46.11444,523.5406,606.7005
08/03/2022 23:59:59.177,0,0,0,1657.427,2123.999,1087.772,6393.695,2158.869,-333.6521,46.11444,523.5406,606.7005
08/03/2022 23:59:59.302,0,0,0,1679.126,2113.148,1087.772,6404.546,2160.206,-311.9535,46.11444,523.5406,597.4413
08/03/2022 23:59:59.426,0,0,0,1657.427,2113.148,1087.772,6393.695,2151.773,-333.6521,56.96551,523.5406,605.2318
08/03/2022 23:59:59.551,0,0,0,1679.126,2113.148,1087.772,6393.695,2160.206,-333.6521,46.11444,523.5406,606.7005
08/03/2022 23:59:59.677,0,0,0,1668.278,2123.999,1087.772,6382.844,2162.988,-333.6521,46.11444,523.5406,606.7005
08/03/2022 23:59:59.801,0,0,0,1657.427,2123.999,1076.921,6382.844,2157.529,-344.5032,46.11444,523.5406,611.683
08/03/2022 23:59:59.926,0,0,0,1679.126,2123.999,1087.772,6404.546,2167.172,-333.6521,46.11444,534.3917,616.3776
08/04/2022 00:00:00.052,0,0,0,1657.427,2123.999,1087.772,6393.695,2158.869,-344.5032,56.96551,523.5406,610.4086
08/04/2022 00:00:00.176,0,0,0,1657.427,2113.148,1076.921,6382.844,2150.376,-344.5032,46.11444,523.5406,611.683
08/04/2022 00:00:00.301,0,0,0,1679.126,2113.148,1087.772,6393.695,2160.206,-344.5032,46.11444,523.5406,611.683
08/04/2022 00:00:00.427,0,0,0,1657.427,2113.148,1087.772,6404.546,2151.773,-333.6521,46.11444,523.5406,606.7005
08/04/2022 00:00:00.551,0,0,0,1646.576,2113.148,1076.921,6393.695,2146.284,-344.5032,46.11444,523.5406,611.683
```

Comment: Consider using [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#functions) to support almost every popular datetime format.

Comment: While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: TYPO: remove one indent from the last line of `ParseTime`.